# Create a C# library which in turn references another library without actually having it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, shared-libraries

I want to create a C# library **HighLevel.dll** which also references another library **LowLevel.dll** with Visual Studio. Both libraries are separate projects in separate repositories. When I add the **LowLevel.dll** as a reference to the **HighLevel.dll** project I actually **need** the compiled **LowLevel.dll** assembly. That also means whoever clones the **HighLevel** library project needs the **LowLevel.dll** in place.
Is it possible to add a reference whithout actually having the target **LowLevel.dll** in place?
If this has something to do with loading a libary at runtime how can this be done?

Comment: "Is it possible to add a reference whithout actually having the target LowLevel.dll in place?" What do you mean here? When your reference is needed, how would you expect it to work on someone elses PC if he/she does not have it? When the reference is needed, it is needed.

Comment: No, if you reference a library, you need it. If you dont reference it but you need tu use it, the other option is loading it up at runtime and either use reflection or `dynamic` to interact with it.

Comment: @InBetween I'm talking of the development phase where I just want to work on one library. A test application may have the additional lib in place. After editing and compiling the assembly it's just pushed back into the repository. The final application will be assembled out of all dedicated libraries. Then they are marriaged first, so to say...  How can I declare the LowLevel.dll in my HighLevel.dll project? In C its just using a header file...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a nuget package, that references other nuget packages.   When someone installs your package, the other nuget packages are automatically pulled in too.

Comment: @Neal I have two library projects and I want to work on each independently. The HighLevel.dll must only know there is a LowLevel.dll with a set of types, classes, etc. A nuget package would have the real compiled assembly, but I don't need it since it is not embedded in the HighLevel.dll? It should only be referenced in a weak way...